# preg_replace first match pattern include slash

Tags: php, regex

How to remove first pattern match when string content "/"

```
$a = "abc/def";
$b = "abc/def/ghi/abc/def";

$result = "/ghi/abc/def"; when replace with "abc/def" only look for the fist match


I try this but is not work.
$x  = preg_replace('/'.$a.'/', '', $b, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep in mind that first argument of preg_replace is a RegEx pattern, so you can't pass just any string to it.

First you need to escape all regex characters with function [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Try:

```
$a = "abc/def";
$b = "abc/def/ghi/abc/def";

$pattern = preg_quote($a, '/'); // second argument allows us to escape delimiter chars, too

$x  = preg_replace("/$pattern/", '', $b, 1);
```

Comment: thank you for help. but is not work for me. what is work for me is  str_replace "/" to other string that work with preg_replace ex.(":"). and str_replace the rest of result back to "/" again.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to enclose the expression in "/" delimiters. Fixed now. Anyway you should use preg_quote when handling a variable as regex pattern. Other way you will need to str_replace every special character like .()[]| and so on. preg_quote does that for you.

Comment: Can you show how you use it and what doesn't work? Isn't that is what you wanted: http://codepad.org/bBpY83IU ?